# Datamodel diagram

Tags: datamodel

what are the relationships we specify in datamodel diagram? And also i have one doubt I have three tables

Table A (emp Id(pk) ,name)
 Table B  (empId(pkfk),depno(pk),department)
 Table C -( contain department list in office)

In Table B creation I referred Fk as empid.so that i drawn  relationship between Table A and TableB.But in TableB department be a a dropdown list it contained list of departments from Table c.Is it necessary to specify the relationship between table b And  c in hierarchy datamodel.

Comment: Homework? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model

Answer (score 1):

Basically you specify the relations between the tables of your datamodel.

For more on this:

[Entity relationship model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model)

[Data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model)

[Relational model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_modelf)